# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty when trying to sign in with Google oAuth

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-openid

I am trying to access Google Drive from an ASP.NET MVC application, and started off with [this sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/GoogleAspNetCoreSamples) by Linda Lawton (one of the contributors to the Google .NET client library).

The sample works fine when run in Visual Studio, but not when deployed to a test site. Here's what happens...

1. I click on the navbar link to the "List files" page, which will then require authentication.
2. I get the oAuth screen (whose URL starts `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount`) where I have to pick a Google user
3. I get a consent screen, where I ahve to confirm that I want to app to access my Google Drive
4. I then get redirected to `http://example.com/signin-oidc` - note that this is not secure, so Edge gives me a warning about this. It doesn't matter if I add the `https` version of the redirect URI to the credentials, it always redirects to the non-secure one
5. If I proceed anyway, I get sent to `https://example.com/signin-oidc`, where I see the following...

> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Anyone any ideas what's going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: thats the redirect uri you are getting really example.com?  if its not https make sure you have this app.UseHttpsRedirection();

Comment: Im pretty sure that sample went along with this blog post and the video https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/   If you cant get it working i will have a look in the morning.

Comment: @DaImTo Yup, that blog post shows basically the same code as in the GitHub sample I linked in my question. No, I'm not using example.com, that's was to obfuscate the real domain. And yes, I already have app.UseHttpsRedirection() in there. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look, as I'm stuck on this one. Thanks

Comment: I will take a look but not sure if I can before the weekend.  check your app settings make sure you remove the option for you system running http

Comment: @DaImTo I'm using CloudFlare, and have it set so that it always redirects to https. I also have `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` in the `Configure` method in `Startup`, so I would have thought that should cover me. Not sure how Google even manages to get to http.